# Find all solutions of the congruence $x^3 \equiv x$ (mod p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number larger than $2$. Find, with proof, all solutions of the congruence $$x^3 \equiv x \, \text{(mod p)}.$$
Is it possible to reduce the congruence to $x^2 \equiv 1 \, \text{(mod p)}$? Then, since $(x^2,p)=1$ there is a unique solution mod p, and so there is $x$ solutions of the original congruence? This thinking seems way off. What do you think?

Comment: Id suggest rewriting it as $p|x^3-x\implies p|x(x^2-1)\implies p|(x-1)x(x+1)$ and work from here.

Answer (score 3):

Rememeber $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field. Thus $$x^3-x=0\iff x(x-1)(x+1)=0\iff \text{ one of } x,x-1,x+1=0$$

Comment: Since $(x-1)x(x+1) \equiv 0$ mod p then solutions for all of the three equations $$x \equiv 1 \, \text{mod p},$$ $$x \equiv 0 \, \text{mod p},$$ $$x \equiv -1 \, \text{mod p}$$ have solutions that solve the original congruence? And so $x=p+1, p$ and $p-1$?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$